# How to create subquery on multiple result columns?

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, both sharing the following columns:

```
table inventory: id, key, timestamp
table stocks: id, key, timestamp
```

I want to select all occurrences of the `key` from `inventory` table together with the minimum timestamp found:

```
SELECT key, MIN(timestamp) as timestamp from inventory GROUP BY key;
```

Using that result, I want to remove anything from `stocks` table where the key matches, and the timestamp is from before the timestamp in the inventory table.

Problem is that I want to return 2 result columns from the `SELECT`, so howc an I reference them during the delete?

Pseudocode:

```
DELETE FROM stocks where key = inventory.key and timestamp < inventory.timestamp;
```

Question: how can I combine those two queries in once go? Maybe with subselect or similar?

Sample data:

```
table inventory;
#id, key, timestamp
1, key1, 2018-10-10
2, key1, 2018-10-10
3, key2, 2018-10-10

table stocks:
#id, key, timestamp
55, key1, 2018-10-10
56, key1, 2018-10-10
57, key2, 2018-10-09
```

As a result, only row with id 57 in table stocks should get removed, because it's timestamp is before the timestamp of the `key2` row in table inventory.

Could I do better than?:

```
DELETE s FROM stocks AS s
JOIN (
    SELECT key, MIN(timestamp) as timestamp FROM inventory GROUP BY key
) as i
WHERE i.key = s.key AND s.timestamp < i.timestamp
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @McNets please have a look on my edit.

Comment: I think it needs: `and s.timestamp < i.timestamp` (reverse check, to remove stocks older than the inventory timestamp)

Comment: Corrected, yes. But my primer question is: is a `JOIN` the way to go here?

Comment: See the tag I added.